# PHP String to Time off by one hour

Tags: php, datetime

I am working with the PHP date and time functions to create my own time between dates calculator and have encountered a problem with the strtotime() function.

When working with a manually entered date and time, calculating the difference between:

20-02-1986 12:00:00 and 04-01-2014 19:31:13

returns what appears to be the correct difference, the first time converted using strtotime() and the second time retrieved using time().

However, if the one of the times is in EDT and the other is in EST, the strtotime() function seems to add an hour as if one of the times is 'falling back' to EST.

17-09-1986 12:00:00 and 04-01-2014 19:37:03

According to timeanddate.com, the difference between the two dates should be:

861,521,823 seconds

but the following code I have produces this:

861,525,423 seconds

There are an extra 3,600 seconds (1 hour). When using strtotime() on 17-09-1986 12:00:00, PHP seems to be working with 17-09-1986 11:00:00.

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York'); 

$today = time();

$pastDate = '17-09-1986 12:00:00'; 
$pastDate = strtotime($pastDate);

$timeAlive = $today - $pastDate;

?>
```

Comment: Could you provide an example without using 'now' and tell us the expected outcome?

Comment: Done, added the exact second representations.

Answer (score 0):

You should convert both dates to GMT, so you can do the difference correctly. PHP is detecting that both times are on the same time zone, so it just does the math, disregarding the time zone change. Converting first should get rid of that problem.